# How can I handle file before it`s downloading?

Tags: file, nginx

I have a nginx-server and if somebody downloads a file, I need to control server output. For example, change output content. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide more details about what you need.

Comment: I need to return base64-encoded files via web-server